# Black screen when I publish ios app via azure devops but when I publish via xcode it works fine

Tags: ios, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, testflight

I'm currently having issues deploying to an iOS app via Azure Pipeline.
If I try to build the app on mac XCode and send it to the store, it will work normally when I open the app on my phone in the testflight.
The problem is that when we try to submit it via Pipeline (the pipeline works normally, and it also has an XCode task), but when we try to open the App on the phone, the screen flashes black and the app closes.

Comment: Check the crash report https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/acquiring-crash-reports-and-diagnostic-logs#Locate-Crash-Reports-and-Memory-Logs-on-the-Device

Comment: We couldn't find any crash Report in neither Apple Organizer in XCode or in the device itself. Do we have to enable it somehow ? By the way, which certificate is the correct one to use when publishing to Testflight track, Development or Distribution ?

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem.  When I deploy successfully to TestFlight, the App deploys and loads on my iPhone.  when it runs, only a white screen (with splash icon) shows up.  The app runs in simulation just fine, but only a white screen In TestFlight.  ???